# Non Blocking socket in C++ - Resource temporarily unavailable error

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I am currently working in a server program in linux, which has to connect to a single client and has to listen to it for commands. Once it receives certain command I have to send some values in return to the client. The values are generated in the main function and the server program is run in a thread.

So, in this case I thought I have to implement non-blocking socket. But I am getting Resource temporarily unavailable error. If any anyone point me in a direction for further research it will would helpful , as I am stuck in this implementation for a long time.

Here is the while loop code,

```
void server::serve() {
struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
socklen_t sin_size;
sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

if(client = accept(sockId,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress,&sin_size) == -1){
    perror("accept");
}

fcntl(sockId,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
fcntl(client,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);

while (1) {
    if(client = accept(sockId,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress,&sin_size) == -1){
        perror("accept");
    }

    cout <<"client "<<client<<endl;
    fcntl(client,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
    getMessage(client);

    if(transmitFlag != -1)
    sendRequest(client);

    }
    closeSocket();
}
```

Comment: If the server needs to listen for messages, why wouldn't it block? What you currently have looks like it's likely to bail out before the client has a chance to send a message. Do you have some `select`-style logic in `getMessage`?

Comment: No, getMessage contains only recv function. I see the issue now, thanks. Which way is the best to solve a issue a issue like this? Where the server has to listen and respond to the incoming message ?

Comment: Without non-blocking socket the application works fine during first iteration but it fails to continue to the next iteration!

Comment: Note that due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the statement `if(client = accept(sockId,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress,&sin_size) == -1)` probably doesn't do what you think it does -- `==` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: Good eyes, @G.M. Som, compiler should have spat out a warning over that. Don't ignore warnings. They are the first line of defense against simple logic errors.

Comment: The best way to rig up something like this is something that blocks with a timeout so that you can exit the loop when you need to. The blocker could be `select` and friends or it could be `recv`. Also remember that TCP is a stream and that `recv` may not return all the data you ask it for if only some o f the data is available.

Comment: @G.M, thanks. I am looking into it.

Comment: Why are you calling `accept()` before entering the loop, and then calling it again inside the loop? Is `serve()` supposed to service 1 client and then exit, or is it supposed to service multiple clients one at a time until the server is terminated? Pick one or the other, don't do both.

Comment: I had made the changes and its working! Thanks,